# 3 Phase Energy Meter to measure multi channel

Tags: current-transformer, power-meter

Can I use single 3-phase energy meter to measure multiple 3 phase load using multiplexing relays for the CT outputs?
For example like below picture.
[image: Multi channel 3 phase data]

The intention is to log data for multiple 3-phase load such as V, I, PF over the time. In the market, there is multi-channel energy logger but the price is too expensive for me.

Comment: If I were doing this I would use three separate meters. EKM omni-meters have a good reputation, although I have not personally used them for anything. They can log data to "the cloud" or wherever you want to log it. My issue with the mux solution is that it might be hard to keep track of which data points go with which load. Also, if you plan to measure cumulative energy usage, I don't think it is a good idea to mux the CT outputs. With missing data, the cumulative average will be off.

Comment: I like the EKM meter ($160) (1pc)  Then there  are mechanical counter types for $20 in China (40A3ph)

Comment: and $54cdn ones with RS485 data. https://www.banggood.com/3-Phase-LCD-Digital-Display-Current-Voltage-Multifunction-Power-Panel-Meter-Power-Energy-Meter-p-1277307.html?rmmds=detail-left-hotproducts__1&HotRecToken=ChQxMzkwODQ5OTAwMTUwMjIwNTUzORACGgJJViICUEQoAA&cur_warehouse=CN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly do this provided that you don't want to record energy usage.

- Voltage will be the same throughout and since they are permanently connected no further work is required.
- Currents are the problem. If you are using typical current transformers then these will have an output of 5 A full scale on the secondaries. Any switching would have to handle that level of current.
- CTs should not be allowed to go open-circuit while current is flowing in the primary. Being *current* transformers the output voltage will go very high in an attempt to drive the current across the open-circuit. This may destroy the CT. CTs have to be short-circuited prior to the meter being disconnected and the switch has to be able to handle 5 A.
- If you can sort out the CT problem then power factor (PF) can be measured.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Pag2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Switching system for one phase of three-phase system.*

The switching circuit would have to guarantee that that only one CT per phase is *not* short-circuited and that the phase being read is connected to the burden in the meter. A rotary switch with 5 A contacts would be required.

I do not recommend your proposal.

Comment: Dear @Transistor, million thanks for your comment. Noted on the CTs should not be allowed to go open-circuit while current is flowing in the primary.